# Ionic View app not retrieving data

Tags: cordova, http, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am busy testing my app, so far it works in my browser but in the **ionic view** (IOS) app it does not.

The problem in the app it self is that it is not loading any data.

> My setup is like this - WCF RESTful <-> IIS <-> app.

So as I mentioned it works in my browser, that means IIS and my Service is working fine. But now I do not know if it is the Ionic View app, IOS or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess would be that you're having problems with 404-erros in your requests.

> If you're using a newer version of Cordova (or the latest Ionic CLI) to develop your app, you may be experiencing http 404 errors when your app tries to make network requests.

This can be solved quickly with [Cordova Whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist).

You can find more documentation on [Ionic docs: Cordova Whitelist](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/cordova-whitelist).

**Solution:**

Run the following command in your shell/terminal:

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```

The only thing you need to do now is to add a property to your `config.xml`
 file:

`<access origin="http://google.com" />`

**Where in the config.xml file should this be placed?** (simplified `config.xml`example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.myApp" version="1.0.0">
    <name>myApp</name>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <!-- Allows access to maps.google.com and docs.google.com -->
    <access origin="http://google.com" subdomains="true" />
    <access origin="https://fonts.googleapis.com"/>
</widget>
```

Comment: Where Do I add the `<allow-navigation href="*" />` is there a specific location in the config file?

Comment: Sorry, the `<allow-navigation href="*" />` notation is specifically for iPhones. For android devices, you will need to add tags like this: `<access origin="http://google.com" subdomains="true" />` 

You can find more information at the documentation of the Whitelist-plugin here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/

Comment: I've just modified my answer, to be more clear. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hm. In which device are you testing this? iOS or Android?

Comment: On my IOS device (Iphone 6)

Comment: Do you've got access to a Apple Developer Account? And where is your data "hosted"? Is this a public API, or something like a localhost server?

Comment: Yes I do but right now I am testing from a Windows PC because I am running a WCF RESTful service locally with IIS..

Comment: Aha, that must be the problem. Are your $http-calls something like this?

`$http({ method: 'GET', url: 'localhost:8080/someUrl'});`

Comment: I haven't tried something like this. But I suppose this should work if both devices are on the exact same network. (Which is the case, I guess?) And if you go to that url, http://192.168.2.112/Service.svc/getTest, what you get to see? Data, or 400, 403, 404-erros?

Comment: Then I suppose this is a 'shortcoming' of the Ionic View app. You could bind the error-response of your $http-request to your page. Just print it, and then you'll know what's causing this.

Comment: I figure it must be an issue with ionic view app I did try to log the error but can't find anything